# adding onclick event on class

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to write a greasemonkey script which adds an `onClick` listener on a button (define below) and do some specific things. I was trying to get this button obj using `document.getElementsByTagName` but it returned `null`. I tried to iterate over `document.anchors` and it returned `null` as well. how can i get this element object and add `onclick` event to it.

```
<a class="editicon" aria-label="Edit this field" role="button" href="#"><img src="https://url-to/images/edit.png?3423434"></a>
```

There is already an onclick added to this object, I don't want to replace it.

**UPDATE**

Adding my Greasemonkey script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        cr
// @namespace   my_namespace
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
  console.log('test ...')
  var editicon = document.getElementsByTagName('editicon');
  console.log(editicon);
})();
```

Comment: Can you include the entire code you used to add the click event?

Comment: added actual code.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` would use `a` not `editicon`. Try that, or use `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @Goose Both `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` return live node lists, which can hurt performance. Since the OP is only seeking a single element, neither of those would be recommended.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree, I only proposed the solution since OP mentioned adding an onclick to a class.

Comment: @Goose Then use `querySelector()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't disagree with what you are saying for getting one element, my comment was in regard to getting a class. I was pointing out a fault in OP's use of `getElementsByTagName` while referencing a class name.

Comment: @Goose With `querySelector()` you can get classes.

Answer (score 1):

First, your question talks about a button, but your code does not include one. Instead of using an `<a>` element and then disabling its native navigation function with `href="#"`, it would be semantically better to use an actual `<button>` element.

Second, you should not use inline HTML event attributes (onclick, onmouseover, etc.) as they:

1. Create "spaghetti code" that doesn't scale, is hard to read, leads to duplication and doesn't follow the **["separation of concerns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)** methodology.
2. Create global anonymous wrapper functions around your event attribute value that alter the `this` binding of your code.
3. Don't follow the **[W3C Event Standard of using the `addEventListener()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)** API.

Now, there are **[several ways to get a reference to a DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)** and some are better than others depending on your HTML structure and how many elements you are trying to get. **[`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)** returns a **["node list"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** of all the elements that were found. Even if no elements were found, you still get this list as the returned object (the list will just be empty when no elements were found). To extract a particular element from the result, you'll need to pass an index into that list, which is an **["array-like" object](http://2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-array-like-objects.html)**. Additionally, `getElementsByTagName` returns a "live" node list, meaning that it will re-scan the document upon every interaction to ensure that the most current list is provided. While this can be beneficial in some circumstances, it comes with a performance cost.

This, for example, would extract the first `a` element in the document:

```
var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

But, since you are only expecting a single element, that is overkill. To get just one element, and if that element has an `id` attribute on it, you can/should use: **[`document.getElementById("theIdHere");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)** as `getElementById()` is generally the fastest way to find a single element in your HTML structure.

Additionally, there are other ways to get an element or elements, like **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** and **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**, which allow you to use CSS selector syntax in your JavaScript queries.

For your code, see the following snippet:

```js
// Get a reference to the first <button> element in the document
var b = document.querySelector("button");

// Or, if the element has an id, the best solution would be:
var b = document.getElementById("btn");

// Add a click event handler to the element
b.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

// Function that will be called when anchor is clicked
function handleClick(){
  alert("You clicked me!");
}
```

```css
button { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); }
img { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<button class="editicon" aria-label="Edit this field" role="button"  id="btn"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/5a/42/c6/5a42c6224e3ce7fa9837965270bfcdd9--smiley-face-images-smiley-faces.jpg"></button>
```